# The class is not being applied to all the divs inside the div

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

Below you will find my HTML code :

```html
<?php

require_once("../RMS/php/component.php")

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-vp86vTRFVJgpjF9jiIGPEEqYqlDwgyBgEF109VFjmqGmIY/Y4HV4d3Gp2irVfcrp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleroles.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Roles</title>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h1 class="py-4 bg-dark text-light rounded"><img src="https://www.flaticon.com/premium-icon/icons/svg/2211/2211680.svg" alt=""> Roles</h1>

            <div class="d-flex  justify-content-center">
                <form action="" method="post" class="w-50">
                    <div class="pt-2">
                        <?php inputElement("<i class='fas fa-id-badge fa-2x'></i>", "ID", "id", "");  ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="pt-2 ">
                        <?php inputElement("<i class='fas fa-user-tie fa-2x'></i>", "Role", "role_name", "");  ?>
                    </div>



                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </main>




</body>

</html>
```

The output of the code :
[image: output]

I want the Role textbox to come in the center as the ID textbox.
Only The ID textbox is justified to the centre.
Even the Role textbox div is inside that div.
But the justify-content-center is just being applied to ID textbox.
I want both the textboxes *justified* to the *center*.
Why is that like that?
I'm looking forward to any solutions you might come up with.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would suffice:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="py-4 bg-dark text-light rounded" style="object-fit: cover;"><img
                src="https://www.flaticon.com/premium-icon/icons/svg/2211/2211680.svg" alt=""> Roles</h1>

        <!-- <div class="d-flex  justify-content-center"> -->
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">

                </div>
                <div class="col-4 pt-2">
                    <i class='fas fa-id-badge fa-2x'></i><input type="text">
                </div>

                <div class="col-4">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">

                </div>
                <div class="col-4  pt-2 ">
                    <i class='fas fa-user-tie fa-2x'></i><input type="text">
                </div>


                <div class="col-4">

                </div>
            </div>
    </div>


    </form>
    <!-- </div> -->
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.1/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

see it working:https://jsfiddle.net/p8v3ownm/

Comment: @itslavanya I have attached its working in fiddle.WHat is missing?? Its in the  center.

Comment: @itslavanya see fiddle

Comment: @itslavanya you can give it a green tick!